# There are 2 dictionaries, I want to append the matching keys from second dictionaries and store them as a list f dictionaries in the parent dictionary

Tags: python

For example, I have below 2 dictionaries,

```
dict1 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'BOB'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'DOD'}]
dict2 = [{'idd': 1, 'comp': 'BB', }, {'idd': 1, 'work': 'pent'}, {'idd': 2, 'comp': 'DD'}]
```

And I want below output -

```
dict1 = [
          {
           'id': 1,
           'name': 'BOB',
           'Details:[
                      {
                       'idd': 1,
                       'comp': 'BB'
                      },
                      {
                       'idd': 1,
                       'work': 'pent'
                       }
                    ]
          },
          {
           'id': 2,
           'name': 'DOD',
           'Details':[
                      {
                       'idd': 2,
                       'comp': 'DD'
                      }
                    ]
          }
        ]
```

I want to get the above result, using dictionary zip or ordereddict

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I tried below -

for i in dict1:
 arr = []
 for j in dict2:
  if i['id'] == j['idd']:
   arr.append(j)
 i.update({'Details':arr})

Comment: Please update your question with this code snippet - code in comments is unreadable - and explain what doesn't work exactly.

Comment: It worked fine, But I don't wanted t use my method.

I am just curious to know how can I achieve the same using zip or ordereddict

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `dict1` to a real dict, with the `id` as key, and add an empty `Details` list to each entry. Then, iterate dict2 and and the missing elements.

```
dict1 = {item['id']: {**item, **{'Details': []}} for item in dict1}

for item in dict2:
    item = dict(item)
    _id = item.pop('idd')
    temp[_id]['Details'].append(item)

dict1 = [item for item in dict1.values()]
```

Comment: I can't run this in IDLE, its showing ' ** ', is invalid syntax.

Comment: @pravashpanigrahi: what python version are you using?